# Downloaded Programs Not Opening on Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista

Don't ask why I'm running vista, but some programs that i've downloaded won't open. They mostly seem to be associated with video games. Some examples would be:

Technic Launcher (http://www.technicpack.net)

Glyph Installer (https://store.trionworlds.com)

I'm not sure how to fix this seeing that I have checked all registries to make sure they are all correct, and that I have re-downloaded the programs/applications. Oddly enought I have been able to download minecraft and Install it but only from the installer .msi file. Does anyone have Suggestions? My specs are below.

Dell XPS M1530
Intel(R) Core(TM) Duo CPU T7500 @ 2.20GHz
3.00 GB RAM
NVIDIA GeForce 8600M GT
250 GB Hard Drive
(Broken) Optical Drive

Comment: What exactly happened when you say "won't open"? Like an error message?

Comment: Do you have an antivirus or firewall that could be blocking them?

Comment: I dont have any firewalls or antivirus software preventing them. When i open them nothing pops up. Not an error message, nor the program.'

Comment: Check Start Menu -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer -> Windows Logs -> Application to see if you can find out anything from the logs.

Answer (score 0):

I know its been a while but maybe this will help future users with the problem. Download installer from glyph.net, find the installer .exe file, right click>properties, compatibility tab, check "run this program as administrator", apply, close window and double click installer. Not sure why but when i right click>run as administrator it did nothing but changing properties worked for me.

Comment: Running an application as an administrator when it's not required is horrible advice it can be down right dangerous with randsomeware

Comment: if you trust the software and your on a Virtual machine, it could be worth it. This tip worked for me. Thank Jason!